# Belarc BenchmarkSummary Error

Tags: installation, security

Installed Belarc but when it is opened it does not display the report. It shows: unknown error BenchmarkSummary((Galceran-PC)).html

Uninstalled and downloaded again from another source. Same Error.
Any ideas?